# How does java.security.Principal work in Spring MVC Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I get Really confused about how  **java.security.Principal** works and how to configure it properly.
My Service Class :

```
@Override
public BarrierPoint addBarrierPoint(Principal principal,String barrierPt,String location) {
    if(checkDuplicate(barrierPt)){return null;}else{
    BarrierPoint barrierPoint = new BarrierPoint();
    barrierPoint.setBarrierPt(barrierPt);
    barrierPoint.setStatus(1);
    barrierPoint.setLocation(location);
    barrierPoint.setCreatedBy(SecurityUtil.getUser(principal).getUserId());
    return barrierPointRepository.save(barrierPoint);
    }
}
```

SecurityUtil Class :

```
public static User getUser(Principal principal)
{
    if(principal instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)
        return ((UserDetails)((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)principal).getPrincipal()).getUser();
    else if(principal instanceof RememberMeAuthenticationToken)
        return ((UserDetails)((RememberMeAuthenticationToken)principal).getPrincipal()).getUser();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Mention precisely so that you can get help from others.

Comment: Can You Now Explain How it works

Comment: Plain Spring MVC or Spring Security... Also WHAT is it you don't understand?

Comment: Plain Spring MVC .How does Principal get to know user Id from UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. What is the main Logic ??

Comment: It doesn't... A `Principal` as a method argument in Spring MVC will receive the value of `HttpServletRequest.getPrincipal`... The rest of your question is Spring Security specific.